# Get ID of layout used in current activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I would like the get the name or resource id of the **layout file** that is used in setContentView inside of an activity.

I can get the id of the root element of the layout file, but I cannot figure out how (or if it is even possible) to get the id of the file that contains the root element.

Example:

Say I have a layout file called **sign_in.xml**, defined as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/layout_id"
      ...
      >
</LinearLayout>
```

After I have my activity, I can call:

```
getView().getId()
```

This will return the id of the LinearLayout inside of sign_in.xml.

What I really want to have is the id of sign_in.xml itself.

Comment: Sounds like you have an XY problem. (also Fragments don't have a `setContentView`). Please explain why you need it and what you would do with that information once you obtained it

Comment: You could scan through `R.layout` somehow to get the name, anyways

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right, I was looking at my activity rather than my fragment. In either case, what I want is still the same. I modified the question to be for an activity rather than a fragment.

The issue with scanning the R file is that I don't know what to look for. I don't have the id of the layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line to get the main file and then it may be possible to get Id as I have not tested yet,

```
  ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
```

**By getting view you can get id or other properties**

Comment: How does that get the name of the XML file that was used?